# Pulling an array from resource file to populate list in android

Tags: android

I'm working through the listbox building example and wanted to alter it to pull an array from the arrays file (going on the separation of code and data thing)

So instead of declaring the array within the class like so

```
private static final String[] items={"A", "B", "C","D", "E", "F"};
```

I have a string array in r.arrays.xml called exercises

```
<resources>
    <array name="exercises">
        <item>Kettlebells - Swing, Two handed</item>
        <item>Kettlebells - Swing, One handed</item>
        <item>Kettlebells - Squat"</item>
        <item>Kettlebells - Deadlift"</item>
        <item>"Kettlebells - Lunge"</item>
        <item>"Kettlebells - Press</item>
    </array>
```

Replaced the existing

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
```

with

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.array.exercises));
```

However, the list doesn't seem to get populated with the array

All help appreciated (from a slightly confused beginner programmer)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] exercises = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);  
ArrayAdapter<String> exercisesAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,exercises);
setListAdapter(exercisesAdapter);
```

Read [android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Comment: fantastic - took me about five attempts just reading through to get my head round but now getting the hang of it

Answer (score 2):

That [constructor's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) arguments aren't what you think they are. The second int is the id of the textView within the layout to use for binding the data. You can use `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.exercises);` to populate `items` and then pass that list to the ArrayAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
Resources res = getResources();
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
               res.getStringArray(R.array.exercises);
```